# Web Service error "Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation"

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm getting the error below when trying to call a web service for HP Operations Orchestration. It appears the WSDL is not properly formatting the response, or I'm not properly handling the response.  Most of the things I've seen online refer to message size being too small.  This doesn't appear to be the case.  I've changed to just using var and that doesn't help.  Any ideas?

The Call: `var h = OOSRClient.getFlowRunHistoryByRunId(1);`

The Exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was caught
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'getFlowRunHistoryByRunId'.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at TestOO.OOSR.WSCentralService.getFlowRunHistoryByRunId(getFlowRunHistoryByRunIdRequest request)
       at TestOO.OOSR.WSCentralServiceClient.TestOO.OOSR.WSCentralService.getFlowRunHistoryByRunId(getFlowRunHistoryByRunIdRequest request) in c:\Users\slippi3\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestOO\TestOO\Service References\OOSR\Reference.cs:line 7526
       at TestOO.OOSR.WSCentralServiceClient.getFlowRunHistoryByRunId(Int64 runId) in c:\Users\slippi3\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestOO\TestOO\Service References\OOSR\Reference.cs:line 7532
       at TestOO.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in c:\Users\slippi3\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestOO\TestOO\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 118
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=There is an error in XML document (1, 1287).
       Source=System.Xml
       StackTrace:
            at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
            at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
            at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
       InnerException: System.InvalidCastException
            HResult=-2147467262
            Message=Cannot assign object of type System.Object[] to an object of type TestOO.OOSR.WSRunHistoryDetailsExtend[].
            Source=ma3ir41a
            StackTrace:
                 at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderWSCentralService.Read90_Item()
                 at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer45.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
                 at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
            InnerException:
```

Here's the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:getFlowRunHistoryByRunIdResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://wscentralservice.services.dharma.iconclude.com">

<getFlowRunHistoryByRunIdReturn soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<getFlowRunHistoryByRunIdReturn xsi:type="ns2:WSRunHistoryDetailsExtend" xmlns:ns2="http://iconclude.com/webservices/rss/v2.0/soap">
<uuid xsi:type="xsd:string">1111ac59-6bbe-47fa-841f-94e56c1b2111</uuid>
<flowRevision xsi:type="xsd:string">4</flowRevision>
<runHistoryId xsi:type="xsd:long">1</runHistoryId>
<runName xsi:type="xsd:string"></runName>
<userId xsi:type="xsd:string">AA\AAAAAAA</userId>
<status xsi:type="xsd:string">Resolved</status>
<startTime xsi:type="xsd:long">1302621361380</startTime>
<duration xsi:type="xsd:long">100</duration>
<numSteps xsi:type="xsd:int">5</numSteps>
<scheduledBy xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
</getFlowRunHistoryByRunIdReturn>
</getFlowRunHistoryByRunIdReturn>
</ns1:getFlowRunHistoryByRunIdResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: FYI, the WSDL is just a document. It doesn't  format the response. I also suggest that (for troubleshooting purposes only) you just catch the exception and display `ex.ToString()`. That way, you'll get all the information the exception wants to tell you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I ended up eventually figuring out that the object the WSDL was trying to get back and the object it was getting back were different.  Ended up writing my own class to handle everything, so far so good.

Answer (score 1):

Problems with the WSDL class generation and what it expected were the issue.  Building my own classes handled it.

Comment: Add some detail to your answer. Show the class you created and how it differs from the auto-generated class. You should also show the relevant part of the WSDL and any speculation you may have on why this happened. You can get upvotes on this answer.